# HTML Canvas: rectangle stroke appears transparent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

To be frankly honest with you, I've got no idea if this is my eye being a b*tch with me or the canvas actually going transparent. The issue seems to be perfectly clear to me however: when I use `strokeRect` (stroke Rectangle), the stroke appears to be transparent no matter what I do.

See screenshot of the stroke: http://prntscr.com/ijeiu9

See screenshot of a normal fill: http://prntscr.com/ijeiz7

My code is as simple as:

```
context.strokeStyle = "#F5F5F5";
context.strokeRect(128, 488, 400, 26);
```

This might even be default behaviour of what I may know, how can I 'fix' this?

Comment: Are you saying that you are seeing only the outline of the rectangle when you use stroke? If so, that is normal behaviour. Use fillStyle to create a filled in rectangle.

Comment: Noo, the issue is that the color, that the `#F5F5F5` is displayed with like, an opacity of `0.75` (random decimal example).

Comment: It's gray - gray always looks that way - you might have a poor display that makes it worse?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, however the `fill` seems to be clearly a full 100% opacity.. It's so weird since I can see any other `#FFF` and `#F5F5F5` properly, take the text for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors) describes this situation as follows:

> Obtaining crisp lines requires understanding how paths are stroked. In
> the images below, the grid represents the canvas coordinate grid. The
> squares between gridlines are actual on-screen pixels. In the first
> grid image below, a rectangle from (2,1) to (5,5) is filled. The
> entire area between them (light red) falls on pixel boundaries, so the
> resulting filled rectangle will have crisp edges.
>
> [image]
>
> If you consider a path from (3,1) to (3,5) with a line thickness of
> 1.0, you end up with the situation in the second image. The actual area to be filled (dark blue) only extends halfway into the pixels on
> either side of the path. An approximation of this has to be rendered,
> which means that those pixels being only partially shaded, and results
> in the entire area (the light blue and dark blue) being filled in with
> a color only half as dark as the actual stroke color.

This means that to get a crisp line of width `1` you should start your rectangle from the half of a pixel:

```js
let a = document.getElementById("a");
let ac = a.getContext("2d");

ac.strokeStyle = "#F5F5F5";
ac.lineWidth = 1;
ac.strokeRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

let b = document.getElementById("b");
let bc = b.getContext("2d");

bc.strokeStyle = "#F5F5F5";
bc.lineWidth = 1;
bc.strokeRect(20.5, 20.5, 150, 100);
```

```css
canvas {width: 300px; height: 150px; background-color:black}
```

```html
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<canvas id="b"></canvas>
```